# Why am I getting extra character at the end of my output?

Tags: c++, string, char, output

```
int start = 0;
int end = 0;
string temp = "<sasadfsadfsady>40000</sadsfasdfsadflary>";
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){

    if (temp[i] == '>' && start == 0)   //will only save first one
        start = i;
    if (temp[i] == '<')
        end = i-start;      //will be overwritten by the second one
}
temp.erase(temp.begin(), temp.begin()+start+1);
temp.erase(temp.begin() + end-1, temp.end());
cout << endl;
cout << temp << end;
```

output:

```
400006
```

why is the 6 at the end? I have no idea why this is happening, please help me

Comment: `temp[i] == temp.length()` doesn't make much sense. "if a character in the string has the same value as the length of the string". that should probably be `if (i == temp.length())`, which also be impossible, since your loop will terminate when i is >= temp.length() anyways.

Answer (score 6):

```
<< end
```

Was probably meant to be

```
<< endl
```

It outputs 6 now because the `int` variable `end` has value 6.

Comment: Another hazard of `using namespace std;`. `std::end` would have failed to compile.

Comment: Actually, now that I try it, I don't just get a compile error. I get a whole lot of template vomit!

Comment: I don't have access to the code right now but there probably is a free standing template function end() in std.